# Can an operator to recognize rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I have some STL container type `T`, say `template< typename F > using T = std::vector< F >;`. I want to be able to write the following code:

```
typedef std::string F;
T< F > v(2, "a"), w(3, "b");
v += std::move(w);
std::cout << "v : ";
std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::ostream_iterator< F >(std::cout, "|"));
std::cout << std::endl << "w : ";
std::copy(std::begin(w), std::end(w), std::ostream_iterator< F >(std::cout, "|"));
std::cout << std::endl;
```

and get the output:

```
v : a|a|b|b|b|
w : |||
```

I.e. I want to be able to append all the contents of the source `w` to the end of the destination `v` by means of "`std::move`-ing" (as one from `<utility>` one by one or as from `<algorithm>` by range), so that all the source's elements remained empty and it will require just `w.clear();` call.

Is it possible to make the operator to recognize the rvalue reference? Say:

```
T & ::operator += (T &, T &&);
```

Or is there something else I should want?

Comment: `error: no match for 'operator+=' in 'foo += std::move<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&>((* & bar))'`

Comment: `int main () {
  std::vector< std::string > foo = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
  std::vector< std::string > bar = {"5", "6"};
  foo += std::move(bar);
  return 0;}`

Comment: that's because you just tried to use `operator+=`, you didn't actually write it!

Comment: Since there is no such operator, then we can reduce the problem to the fact that the container is the user-defined one. I cannot declare the `operator +=` as non-member function, so that this is the case.

Comment: `operator=` must be a non-static member function, but `operator+=` doesn't need to be

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that will work, but `T` is not a type so you can't write the operator like that. `T` is a template, so the operator would need to be something like

```
template<typename U>
  T<U>& operator+=(T<U>&, T<U>&&);
```

A possible implementation would be:

```
template<typename U>
  T<U>& operator+=(T<U>& lhs, T<U>&& rvalue)
  {
    std::move(rvalue.begin(), rvalue.end(), std::back_inserter(lhs));
    rvalue.clear();
    return lhs;
  }
```

And overloaded for lvalues:

```
template<typename U>
  T<U>& operator+=(T<U>& lhs, const T<U>& lvalue)
  {
    std::copy(lvalue.begin(), lvalue.end(), std::back_inserter(lhs));
    return lhs;
  }
```

To make this work with any type (which I consider a bad idea, it should be constrained to only match the types you want) try this:

```
template< class T, class U >
  inline
  typename std::enable_if< std::is_lvalue_reference< U >::value, T& >::type
  operator += (T& lhs, U&& lvalue)
  { /* copy from lvalue */ }

template< class T, class U >
  inline
  typename std::enable_if< !std::is_lvalue_reference< U >::value, T& >::type
  operator += (T& lhs, U&& rvalue)
  { /* move from rvalue */ }
```

Comment: But I would have done some optimization: `template< class T, class U >
inline
T & operator += (T & lhs, U && rhs)
{
    if (((void *)&lhs != (void *)&rhs) && !rhs.empty()) {
        std::move(std::begin(rhs), std::end(rhs), std::back_inserter(lhs));
        rhs.clear();
    }
    return lhs;
}`

Comment: How to achieve the next behaviour: for non-temporaries or non-`std::move(*)`-ed objects I want to use other version of operator, which does not clear the source? Naive operator overloading leads to nothing. The version with `T &&` is called anyway. Should I use the `boost::enable_if<>`?

Comment: Why is that an optimisation? how often do you do self-assignment? how often _from an rvalue_?  The answers should be almost never and **never** ... it's not possible to assign a temporary to itself, and if you write `a += std::move(a)` you're a fool! the "optimisation" just adds extra code to slow it down.

Comment: your overload must be written wrong, the `T<F>&&` overload cannot be called for non-rvalues

Comment: Ok, ok =))). Chill out, dude.

Comment: I already tried this, but it not work (when I modified this for `template< class T, class U >
inline
T & operator += (T & lhs, U && rhs)` and `template< class T, class U >
inline
T & operator += (T & lhs, U const & rhs)` versions, then only first called in all cases).

Comment: Look at what I wrote more carefully, then look at what you wrote, not the same, right? In your code `U&&` binds to anything, it's what Scott Meyers calls a [universal reference](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers). Look at my code, `T<U>&&` will only bind to an rvalue, and so `const T<U>&` will be used for lvalues.

Comment: Why are you calling `std::move` with those arguments in the 2nd example. Sure you didn't mean for it to be `std::copy`?

Comment: @David, I assume you're asking Dukales about his comment, not about my answer?  You're right, the code in the comment is broken. For some reason he is ignoring my answer and writing something different, then complaining it doesn't work.

Comment: I admit it. My mistake. But I want to improve the code further perhaps not even in the question posed.

Comment: What do I need to do to work my prototype (with universal reference)?

Comment: `template< class T, class U >
inline
typename std::enable_if< std::is_lvalue_reference< U >::value, T & >::type operator += (T & lhs, U rhs)` does not work

Comment: That doesn't use a universal reference. See my updated answer